# Will data be preserved if innodb_buffer_pool_size is changed?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to disable the buffer pool in order to free up some memory.
I guess it will not affect the current innodb data. I want to keep the InnoDB tables thought I will not be using them on this server.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
```

Can someone confirm that disabling this line will not affect the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to remove the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` line, which will cause the buffer pool to be sized according to the compile-time default for MySQL, which depends on the version. You could also just adjust it to a different value. The data will not be affected, although it may be slower to access it (and it sounds like you are OK with that).

Answer (score 1):

in accordance to my knowledge it is not good to disable it you can change it to a value which is minimum

why because even you are using them on the other server the remote server first checks the data in buffer pool to retrieve from the local server

what i mean is if data is there in buffer pool your local server can easily satisfy the request made by the remote server

if you want quick response from the local server you should not disable it...